# nginx SSL redirect not working

Tags: express, nginx

I have nginx configured to forward traffic to an express server and want to force SSL by redirecting traffic directed at http:// to https://. I've done extensive googling on the subject however can not get this to work. HTTPS is working fine but so is HTTP - the redirect does not appear to be having any effect.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name my.domain www.my.domain;
    return 301 https://my.domain$request_uri;
}
server {

    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name my.domain www.my.domain;

    ssl_certificate     /home/user/my_domain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/user/my_domain.key;


    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/mydomain.access.log;

    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      proxy_pass          https://localhost:3000;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

      proxy_redirect      https://localhost:3000 https://my.domain;
    }

}
```

Comment: Assuming you did `nginx reload|restart` to reload the config, `nginx -t` make sure the config is correct, `nginx -T` make sure the config is seen.

Comment: it doesn't seem reload is a valid command, nor is -T. I'm using the latest nginx on Ubuntu 14.04.

-t reports the config is OK and other changes are being applied when I restart the service

Answer (score 0):

i have also the same problem so I apply these to server to accept only one request which will decide for both http and https

```
server { 
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    listen 443 ssl http2 ;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ;
    server_name example.com www.example.com; 

    #------ ssl certificates and other config --------

    set $https_redirect 0;
    #if request came from port 80/http
    if ($server_port = 80) { 
        set $https_redirect 1; 
    }
    # or if the requested host came with www 
    if ($host ~ '^www\.') { 
        set $https_redirect 1; 
    }
    #then it will redirects
    if ($https_redirect = 1) {
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

by using this I have only server block to hanlde any request